# Update other row(s) with sequencing value based on previously updated row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
SELECT ID, Rank
FROM FAQ
ORDER BY Rank ASC;
```

| ID | Rank |
| --- | --- |
| 21 | 1 |
| 25 | 2 |
| 30 | 3 |
| 23 | 4 |
| 24 | 5 |
| 26 | 6 |
| 27 | 7 |
| 28 | 8 |
| 29 | 9 |
| 22 | 10 |

Now, I'm updating a row:

```
UPDATE FAQ SET
    Rank = 8
WHERE ID = 30;

SELECT ID, Rank
FROM FAQ
ORDER BY Rank ASC;
```

| ID | Rank |
| --- | --- |
| 21 | 1 |
| 25 | 2 |
| 23 | 4 |
| 24 | 5 |
| 26 | 6 |
| 27 | 7 |
| 28 | 8 |
| 30 | 8 |
| 29 | 9 |
| 22 | 10 |

My question: is there a way to update the other row ID (23, 24, 26, 27, 28) from original Rank (4, 5, 6, 7, 8) to new Rank (3, 4, 5, 6, 7), respectively?

I have tried:

```
DECLARE @SrNo SMALLINT = 0;

UPDATE FAQ SET @SrNo = Rank = @SrNo + 1;
```

after the update but to no avail, as it will just return the Rank value as per the first image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: You'll need to use the function `row_number` to generate new numbers.

Comment: @DaleK row_number() to generate the new numbers and update the other rows?

Comment: You've got a harder problem there, that is finding an earlier gap. If you use decimal values you can continue to insert into the gaps, i.e. you can put 7.5 between 6 & 7. Then reorder afterwards. What if you have no earlier gaps? Then would you renumber forwards? Requiring an ordered sequence with no gaps is frequently more trouble than its worth. What do you use the rank for?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the code below and create a stored procedure:

```
DECLARE  @FAQ TABLE (
    ID INT,
    [Rank] INT
);

INSERT INTO @FAQ (ID, [Rank])
VALUES
    (21, 1),
    (25, 2),
    (30, 3),
    (23, 4),
    (24, 5),
    (26, 6),
    (27, 7),
    (28, 8),
    (29, 9),
    (22, 10);

DECLARE @ID INT = 30
       ,@Rank INT = 8;

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY IIF(ID = @ID, @Rank, [Rank]), IIF(ID = @ID, IIF(@Rank > [Rank], 1, -1), 0)) AS [new_rank] AS [new_rank]
    FROM @FAQ
)
UPDATE DataSource
SET [Rank] = [new_rank]
WHERE [Rank] <> [new_rank];

SELECT ID, [Rank]
FROM @FAQ
ORDER BY [Rank] ASC;
```

[image]

We are using `ROW_NUMBER` in order to order the data based on the new rank value for a particular row. For rows with the same value, the updated one is treated as bigger.

Comment: I believe this could work, but can you please explain this part here? `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY IIF(ID = @ID, @Rank, [Rank]), IIF(ID = @ID, 1, 0))` especially on the ORDER BY and IIF.

Comment: Well, it's pretty simple - we want to order the rows using ROW_NUMBER function to generate order ID. The first part is `IIF(ID = @ID, @Rank, [Rank])` which means, if the current row rank is updated, use the new value, if not - use the current value. This will lead to two rows having the same rank, so the second ordering criteria `IIF(ID = @ID, 1, 0)` simply tells - if this is the updated row, it should have bigger order ID.

Comment: Great answer. Does require a full sort on the whole table though.

Comment: @Charlieface good point - in such case the logic can be expanded in the `IIF(ID = @ID, 1, 0)` -adding something like `IIF(@Rank > [Rank], 1, -1)`, I will change it.

Comment: Try `SIGN(@Rank - Rank)` like in my answer

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different, and possibly more efficient, version of @gotqn's excellent answer:

```sql
DECLARE  @FAQ TABLE (
    ID INT primary key,
    [Rank] INT
);

INSERT INTO @FAQ (ID, [Rank])
VALUES
    (21, 1),
    (25, 2),
    (30, 3),
    (23, 4),
    (24, 5),
    (26, 6),
    (27, 7),
    (28, 8),
    (29, 9),
    (22, 10);

DECLARE @ID INT = 30
       ,@Rank INT = 8;
DECLARE @OldRank INT = (SELECT Rank FROM @FAQ RowToMove WHERE RowToMove.ID = @ID);

UPDATE ToUpdate
SET Rank = IIF(ToUpdate.ID = @ID, @Rank, ToUpdate.Rank + SIGN(@OldRank - @Rank))
FROM @FAQ ToUpdate
WHERE ToUpdate.Rank BETWEEN
    LEAST(@OldRank, @Rank) AND GREATEST(@OldRank, @Rank);

SELECT ID, [Rank]
FROM @FAQ
ORDER BY [Rank] ASC;
```

Essentially, you begin by looking up the existing rank of the single row you want to move.

Then take all the rows between that rank and the new rank (taking the lower and higher of those in order). Update that set of rows as follows: if it's the row we want to change, set it to `@Rank`, otherwise add to it the `SIGN` of the difference between the rank moves ie +1 or -1. This therefore works no matter which direction the row is moving.

It also does not require a sort on the rows, as long as there is an index on `ID`

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZjadTeBK)

Comment: Charlieface
I put everything in excel to better understand the logic and I can only vote and admire your solution.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Generate `Row_Number` order by `Id` and hopefully it will satisfy your desired output. Make sure how you generating Rank order by. Because 22 with rank 10

```
with cte as (
    select *, row_number() over (order by Id) as RwNo from FAQ 
)
update cte set Rank = RwNo;
```

Generation of the Rank on the fly is best approach instead of storing in the table.